# What is the difference between "checken", "nachprüfen" and "kontrollieren"?

Tags: meaning, difference, verb, verb-choice, verb-usage

> Ich muss mal das Haus kontrollieren, ob wirklich alle Fenster zu sind.

Can I use *nachprüfen* or *checken* in this context? What is the difference between *nachprüfen*, *checken* and *kontrollieren*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say in the context you have given "nachprüfen/kontollieren" mean the same.
"checken" is a new expression, probably only used by the younger generation. And it would be felt as an English foreign body in German by the older generations.

Comment: So, you're suggesting that "Ich muss mal das Haus nachprüfen" is fine? Is that really what you would say? I really doubt that.

Comment: I think the context was: Ich muß mal nachprüfen/kontrollieren, ob alle Fenster geschlossen sind. And both verbs are fine for me.

Comment: Then say that. From your answer that's not clear. Not at all. OP's sentence is different from what you're phrasing and as long as you do not make that clear, it's not obvious what you're having in mind.

Comment: from the context of the question it is quite clear

Answer (score 5):

`Checken`, derived from the English check, is rather colloquial. You wouldn't use it in a formal context, let alone in writing. There are also other meanings:

> Ich check das nicht! (I don't understand!)
>
> Ich hab uns zwei Tickets gecheckt. (I managed two get two tickets for us.)

The two other terms, `kontrollieren` and `nachprüfen` mean similar things, although there are subtle differences. *Kontrollieren* is rather neutral: you check something, make sure that everything is in order. A police checkpoint, e.g., would be *Straßenkontrolle* in German (they'll want to see your driver licence, perhaps check sobriety.)

*Nachprüfen*, on the other hand, implies that there has been a *Vor-Prüfung* of sorts, you have an idea, a preconceived notion, a suspicion that you want to check upon. Or, an auditor takes a second look at a company's books, making sure that book-keeping is in order; things like that.

Comment: Probably a cultural/regional difference, but I always felt like 'kontrollieren' had very negative and authoritative connotations. Think 'Kontrollwahn'/'Kontrollfreak' etc. 'Nachprüfen' on the other hand is (to me) quite harmless. As I understood it as 'noch einmal (nach dem Ersteller) prüfen', like in school.

Comment: http://www.rp-online.de/nrw/staedte/duesseldorf/frau-stirbt-bei-verkehrsueberpruefung-aid-1.1109096